# How to create a labeles dataset for 9170 image classses: Path directory

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dataset

I'm newbie here and I want to implement a neural network using keras.
I have a dataset having over 9000 classes. Each class is contained in a specific folder. I want to organize them for training and validation. Inspired from dog/cat dataset simple example, I know that I have to make all the 9000++ classes like that :

```
CAT_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Cat/"
TRAINING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/"
TESTING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/"
DOG_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Dog/"
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/"
TESTING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/"
```

But doing that for 9000 seems a lot, is there any solution, please?

**Edit:** here is the dataset that I'm working on:
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwa7c5uz7cac7cw/VMMRdb.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Do you mean 9000 images? If you're doing cat and dogs, it seems like you are going to have 2 classes

Comment: No Bro I mean 9000 classes  :/ not images I have to predict the model of a car I have 9000 classes in this dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does seem a lot but using `glob` and `os` libraries of Python, you can easily create such a directory structure. BTW, you are working on interesting problem, try using ArcFace loss for this, it will help you.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I have another question please, the name of the folders are already the name of the classes, using Keras. Can it automatically learn that or do I have to specify?

Comment: Are you talking about class to number mapping?

Comment: Yes , That what I'm talking about , I found a solution thanks :D